# Display Rich Text in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I am trying to display the rich text in a list item . I tried using the JSON formating, but it does not seem to have any support for "Enhanced rich text".

The txtcontent converts the rich text to plain text i.e. `<div><b>my text</b></div>.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Multi line of Text and Enhanced rich text option is checked.. By Default List views display it in html format. below is screenshot of your example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never really tried, but I don't think it's possible. The [schema](https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json) has only the `txtContent` property, which get's inserted as "text", not as "html". I see no way to insert "html" content. You'd need an [SPFx Field Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) for that.